# How to get links from an opened IE page

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, ole

How can I control an IE page that is already opened, for which I only have the handle?

The following code retrieves the links from a web page. I want to do the same, but I only have the handle from IE, because the page is already opened.

How can I do it?

```
Var
  I, n : Integer;
  IEApp: OLEVariant;
begin
  if(VarIsEmpty(IEApp))then
  begin
    IEApp := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
    IEApp.Visible := true;
  end;
  IEApp.Navigate('www.google.com');
  while Cardinal(IEApp.readyState) <> 4 do sleep(1000);
  n := Cardinal(IEApp.Document.links.length);
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(string(IEApp.Document.links.item(i).href));
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "the handle from IE", but to list all the links from the first IE instance's (given by the [`Shell.Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774107(v=vs.85).aspx) method) document, you may write [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/saM85ykD).

Comment: @TLama : why don't you paste that code as an answer here?

Comment: @Wouter, because that check of `IEXPLORE.EXE` looks weird there to me. I took the inspiration from the community addition of [`this page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx), but hard to say if it's the "right way" to get IE instance. That it works is not always the "best" you can get. But feel free to take it to post (I can even delete my comment from here; just let me know).